# Bitcoin-QT client shows coins, but cannot find wallet.dat

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, synchronization, wallet.dat

It's been a couple years, and I opened my bitcoin-qt client.  It says I have coins, but is taking days to "sync with network".

Further, I cannot find a wallet.dat file anywhere on my system.

How can it know I have coins without a wallet?

I'm on the same computer I had two years ago, and didn't delete any files from my ~library/application support/bitcoin or any other bitcoin related files... sooo... befuddled.

Any insights, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already looked there, but when I open a terminal and enter
`ls -la ~/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin/` 
I see all the files there, including `wallet.dat`. Please note the backslash before the folder name space.

Comment: You can also search using find on the entire hard disk.